# Operation on string in PHP. Remove part of string

Tags: php, string, cut, substr

How can i remove part of string from example:

> @@lang_eng_begin@@test@@lang_eng_end@@
>   @@lang_fr_begin@@school@@lang_fr_end@@
>   @@lang_esp_begin@@test33@@lang_esp_end@@

I always want to pull middle of string: `test, school, test33`.  from this string. 
I Read about ltrim, substr and other but I had no good ideas how to do this. Becouse each of strings can have other length for example :

> 'eng', 'fr'

I just want have string from middle between @@ and @@. to Maye someone can help me? I tried:

```
foreach ($article as $art) {

                $title = $art->titl = str_replace("@@lang_eng_begin@@", "", $art->title);
                $art->cleanTitle = str_replace("@@lang_eng_end@@", "", $title);
            }
```

But there

> @@lang_eng_end@@

can be changed to

> @@lang_ger_end@@

in next row so i ahvent idea how to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your strings are *always* in this format, an `explode` way looks easy:

```
$str = "@@lang_eng_begin@@test@@lang_eng_end@@ "; 
$res = explode("@@", $str)[2];
echo $res;
```

You may use a regex and extract the value in between the non-starting `@@` and next `@@`:

```
$re = "/(?!^)@@(.*?)@@/"; 
$str = "@@lang_eng_begin@@test@@lang_eng_end@@ "; 
preg_match($re, $str, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/sqkC9J). Here, the regex matches a `@@` that is not at the string start (`(?!^)@@`), then captures into Group 1 any 0+ chars other than newline as few as possible (`(.*?)`) up to the first `@@` substring.

Or, replace all `@@...@@` substrings with `preg_replace:

```
$re = "/@@.*?@@/"; 
$str = "@@lang_eng_begin@@test@@lang_eng_end@@ "; 
echo preg_replace($re, "", $str);
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/8vSwZY). Here, we just remove all non-overlapping substrings beginning with `@@`, then having any 0+ chars other than a newline up to the first `@@`.

Comment: Wow thanks :) I forgot about preg_match :) Have a nice day :)